# ASP.NET Identity 2 and Anonymous Users

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, anonymous-users

In our developing e-commerce solution we are using AspNet Identity 2.2.1 and it is required that any guest (anonymous) users should complete checkout without prior registration to the website. In order to fullfill this requirement have written an ActionFilter named UserMigrationAttribute which obtains SessionTrackId (string GUID) from cookie -which we set from a HttpModule for every request if SessionTrackId is not found along with request cookies- and creates and actual IdentityUser in database with the username something like SessionTrackId@mydomain.com.

We have decorated our BaseController class with this UserMigration attribute in order to utilize its functions throughout the site.

Everything up to this point works as expected with single downside issue, which is when the page is being loaded for the first time for any user, if we try to make an Jquery Ajax Call to a Method which have `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute, the call fails with the '`The provided anti-forgery token was meant for a different claims-based user than the current user.`' error, even though we are sending `__RequestVerificationToken` parameter with every ajax call.

But if user opens another page by clicking link and/or reloads/refreshes current page, all the subsequent ajax calls complete successfully.

In our understanding UserMigrationAttribute creates user on OnActionExecuting method, but after we signIn user in the process @Html.AntiForgeryToken() is not being updated with the right values.

You may find the UserMigrationAttribute code below;

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
    public class UserMigrationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public ApplicationSignInManager SignInManager(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            return filterContext.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
        }

        public UserManager UserManager(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            return filterContext.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<UserManager>();
        }

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            CreateMigrateCurrentUser(filterContext);
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }

        private static readonly object LockThis = new object();

        private void CreateMigrateCurrentUser(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            lock (LockThis)
            {
                var signInManager = SignInManager(filterContext);
                var userManager = UserManager(filterContext);

                var sessionTrackId = GetSessionTrackId(filterContext);

                if (!filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sessionTrackId))
                    {
                        var username = string.Format("{0}@mydomain.com", sessionTrackId);
                        var user = userManager.FindByName(username);

                        if (user == null)
                        {
                            user = new User() {UserName = username, Email = username};
                            var result = userManager.Create(user);
                            userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, StringResources.AnonymousVisitorsGroup);
                        }

                        signInManager.SignIn(user, true, true);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sessionTrackId))
                    {
                        var username = string.Format("{0}@mydomain.com", sessionTrackId);
                        var user = userManager.FindByName(username);

                        if (user != null)
                        {
                            if (!HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole(StringResources.AnonymousVisitorsGroup))
                            {
                                var targetUserId = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId<int>();

                                var service = new Service();
                                service.Users.MigrateUser(user.Id, targetUserId);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

        }

        private string GetSessionTrackId(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            var retVal = string.Empty;
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["stid"] != null)
            {
                retVal = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["stid"].Value;
            }

            return retVal;

        }

    }
```

Any help or suggestions are highly appreciated.

Thank you,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because the anti-forgery token is set in a cookie, which will not be updated until the next request. If you're manually signing a user in, you should also issue a redirect (even if to the same page they were already headed to), simply to ensure that the cookie data is correct. This normally happens naturally, as the sign in form will redirect to the URL that needed authorization after the user is signed in, thus negating the problem. Since you're not redirecting currently, the data is out of sync.

However, I have to say that this seems like a very poor solution to this particular use case. Creating some sort of temporary-type user and signing that user in to handle guest checkout creates an unnecessary glut of useless data in your database, at best, and leads to bugs and other issues like this one you're experiencing, at worst.

I also run an ecommerce site, and the way we handled guest checkout is incredibly simplistic. The checkout data is just stored in the session (email, shipping/billing address, etc.). We build a view model to handle the actual checkout where the data necessary for submitting the sale comes either from the user object, if they're logged in, or these session variables, if they aren't. If the user is neither logged in, nor has the requisite session variables set, then they are redirected to the onboarding form where billing/shipping, etc. is collected.

For other aspects like maintaining an anonymous cart, we use a permanent cookie with the cart identifier. If the user ends up creating an account, we associate the anonymous cart with their user, and then remove the cookie. This ensures that their cart survives past the session timeout and things like closing the browser, even if they're anonymous.

In other words, in all these things, no user object is actually needed. If it's there (user is logged in), great, we'll use it. Otherwise, we collect and persist the requisite information for checkout via other means.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and guidance, this is the accepted answer as it suggests (self) redirect on filterContext thus solving our problem.